# COM typelibrary for Office 2010 IM integration

Tags: com, ms-office, office-interop, lync-2013

I am integrating Office applications with custom IM solution.
I have implemented the COM class as suggested by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715.aspx

I have also registered the COM implementation and hosted the COM server in my exe.

Do I also need to additionally register the typelibrary of my com class ?

I am seeing issues with type library regsitration and lync client 2013.

When I uninstall the type library, Lync Client breaks

> Generic COM Exception. Code is 0x80080005.
>    at Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.EnsureOI()
>    at Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient()

I understand that Lync 2013 provides its own typelib which I am overwriting.

Is it required for me to register my typelib for Office integration to work ?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is dated but I ran into this problem today.  I found [this article](http://thoughtstuff.co.uk/2012/07/using-lync-2010-applications-with-lync-2013-and-lync-2013-applications-with-lync-2010/) that points to having both Lync 2010 and Lync 2013 installed on the same machine.

**Uninstalling Lync 2010 worked perfectly for me.**  COM operations began working immediately.