# Lync Client Generic COM Exception

Tags: c#, com, lync, skype-for-business

We are doing Windows based automation software that uses the `Skype lync SDK` library.

Using `Microsoft.Lync.Model` I am trying to send a message to another Skype for Business user from a C# application with below given code:

```
LyncClient lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient();
Conversation conversation = lyncClient.ConversationManager.AddConversation();
```

But it gives following error :

> Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClientException: 'Generic COM Exception. Code
>   is 0x8002802B.'

Any help in this case will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: From this [MSDN How to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj937298.aspx) it appears that your sample code is missing some important parts. Like, making sure you're signed in and registering handlers for `ConversationAdded` and `ParticipantAdded` f.e. Not sure what is required, but it might be good to follow that guide first.

Comment: Already added this handlers for ConversationAdded and ParticipantAdded, But this code not work.

Comment: Could you find any solution for this issue??? @ChetanNikam

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already looked elsewhere for related/similar issues. This error showed up several times in the past, not all threads are *that* conclusive though. In case, here are some pointers:

- [Here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073602/540776), where the answer is to make sure you have **one and only one** client version installed on your/any machine. Similarly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575313/lyncclientexception-when-trying-to-run-windows-service/31580818), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894020/com-typelibrary-for-office-2010-im-integration/20498860#20498860) and on [this blog](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2012/07/using-lync-2010-applications-with-lync-2013-and-lync-2013-applications-with-lync-2010/), which should be the original reference
- Also mixing 64/32 bit between SDK and build target seems to cause the issue, as mentioned on [this GH project](https://github.com/tomorgan/Lync-UISuppression-VideoAutoAnswer/issues/5), although this is produces a *different* error code
- The official MS Lync Client Dev forum, looking for [this specific error code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/home?forum=communicatorsdk&sort=relevancedesc&brandIgnore=True&searchTerm=0x80080005)